# Char array-size changes when used as a function parameter

Tags: c, arrays

I'm wondering why this method of determining the array-size give "the answer" I had in mind.

Following my interpretation, the output of the `test2()` is correct, considering the null-pointer that is included in the size. But I don't know what happens when using `test1(char *s)`.

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test1(char *s);
void test2(); 
int main() {
    char s[] = "aaa";
    test1(s);
    test2();
    return 0;
}
void test1(char *s) {
    printf("cstring: %s\n", s);

    int size = sizeof(s)/sizeof(char);
    printf("size: %d\n",size);

    int test[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    size = sizeof(test)/sizeof(int);

    printf("size: %d\n",size);
}

void test2() {
    printf("@test:\n");
    char s[] = "aaa";
    int size = sizeof(s)/sizeof(char);
    printf("size: %d\n", size);
    int i[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    size = sizeof(i)/sizeof(int);
    printf("size: %d\n", size);
}
```

### Output

```
cstring: aaa
size: 8
size: 5
@test:
size: 4
size: 5
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: Looks good to me, you are overriding `int size = 3` in your `test1 (char *s)`.

Comment: In `test1()`, `sizeof(s)/sizeof(char)` gives 4 not because `s` points to a "string" with 4 chars, but because the size of a pointer on your machine *happens* to be 4.

Comment: @Emz, I'm sorry, the previous code was incorrect. I forgot to paste some lines

Comment: regarding this line: `int size = sizeof(s)/sizeof(char);`   the 'sizeof' operator is a compile time item.  and in this case will return the number of bytes in the pointer 's' (I.E. for a 32 architecture it will return 4).  Where that '4' has nothing to do with the string array that 's' points to.

Comment: to get the size of a passed in pointer to an array,  use `size_t arrayLen = strlen( s);`   which will need `#include <string.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function test1, you only have a char pointer (`char*`), not an array. So, `sizeof(s)` will return the size of the pointer: could be 4 with a 32 bits build or 8 if you build in 64 bits.

If you are sure to have a null-terminated string, use `strlen()` instead, otherwize, add a `size_t size` parameter to your function.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks. I would accept this answer, but unfortunately I can't due points.

Comment: It's ok, the more important is that you understood your problem and can move on... :)